Is being $S_2$ an étale-local property?
I know that normality is étale local i.e., if we have $Y\rightarrow X$ étale with $X$ normal then $Y$ is normal. But is this true if we replace "normal" with "satisfies Serre's $S_2$"? More generally, does it hold for Serre's $S_k$?
Say $Y\rightarrow X$ is finite étale, then $Y$ is proper. So maybe we can use proper base change to conclude by the cohomological characterization of $S_k$ (see here).

The  $S_n$ property can be formulated via vanishing of local cohomology.  This can be checked after completion.

By flatness of $Y\to X$, a regular sequence in a local ring on $X$ produces a regular sequence in a local ring on $Y$.

While @PiotrAchinger's argument looks easier, this is also Tag 0352.

It's even syntomic local, see Tag 036A. Also, there are different notions of "local"; the Stacks project uses this definition which in turn depends on the exact definition of coverings for each topology one considers.
